# Oblique matrix numeration

Tags: algorithm, matrix

I have a square matrix of size n, and this matrix contains numbers from 1 to n ^ 2 arranged as follows:

[Matrix numeration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bgT5A.jpg)

Etc.

Knowing the number of the element of matrix, I need to find out the number of the column and row in which it is located.
Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: This is called "Zigzag" or diagonal traversal

Comment: no, it's not diagonal traversal matrix

Comment: Write down a few more members of the sequence of largest numbers on each diagonal (1, 3, 6, ...) Looks familiar? If not, perhaps look it up on [oeis](https://oeis.org).

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have a solution, here is the python code:

```
num = int(input())
sum = 1
i = 1
while (num>sum):
    i += 1
    sum += i
diff = sum - num
if (i%2):
    Y = i - diff
    X = diff + 1
else:
    Y = diff + 1
    X = i - diff
```

In this way, we calculate the number of the diagonal on which the number lies (and this is useful, because adjacent numbers on the diagonals differ by one). This is possible due to the fact that each diagonal contains 1 more number than the previous one.

Next, we look at the parity of the diagonal number. In combination, this is the number of numbers on the diagonal, and in the simplest way we calculate the position of the number in the matrix. You can experiment.